# Bash script function call error

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing my first Bash script and am running into a syntax issue with a function call.

Specifically, I want to invoke my script like so:

```
sh myscript.sh -d=<abc>
```

Where `<abc>` is the name of a specific directory inside of a fixed parent directory (`~/app/dropzone`). If the child `<abc>` directory doesn't exist, I want the script to create it before going to that directory. If the user doesn't invoke the script with a `-d` argument at all, I want the script to exist with a simple usage message. Here's my best attempt at the script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
dropzone="~/app/dropzone"

# If the directory the script user specified exists, overwrite dropzone value with full path
# to directory. If the directory doesn't exist, first create it. If user failed to specify
# -d=<someDirName>, exit the script with a usage statement.
validate_args() {
    args=$(getopt d: "$*")
    set -- $args
    dir=$2
    if [ "$dir" ]
    then
        if [ ! -d "${dropzone}/targets/$dir" ]
        then
            mkdir ${dropzone}/targets/$dir
        fi
        dropzone=${dropzone}/targets/$dir
    else
        usage
    fi
}

usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0" >&2
    exit 1
}

# Validate script arguments.
validate_args $1

# Go to the dropzone directory.
cd dropzone
echo "Arrived at dropzone $dropzone."

# The script will now do other stuff, now that we're in the "dropzone".
# ...etc.
```

When I try running this I get the following error:

```
myUser@myMachine:~/app/scripts$ sh myscript.sh -dyoyo
mkdir: cannot create directory `/home/myUser/app/dropzone/targets/yoyo': No such file or directory
myscript.sh: 33: cd: can't cd to dropzone
Arrived at dropzone /home/myUser/app/dropzone/targets/yoyo.
```

Where am I going wrong, and is my general approach even correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212219/passing-parameters-to-a-bash-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the function definitions to the top of the script (below the hash-bang). `bash` is objecting to the undefined (at that point) call to `validate_args`. `usage` definition should precede the definition of `validate_args`.

There also should be spacing in the if tests "[ " and " ]".

```
    if [ -d "$dropzone/targets/$1" ]
```

The `getopt` test for option d should be-:

```
    if [ "$(getopt d "$1")" ]
```

Here is a version of validate_args that works for me.
I also had to change the drop zone as on my shell ~ wouldn't expand in mkdir command.

```
dropzone="/home/suspectus/app/dropzone"

validate_args() {
    args=$(getopt d: "$*")
    set -- $args
    dir=$2
    if [ "$dir" ]
    then
        if [ ! -d "${dropzone}/targets/$dir" ]
        then
            mkdir ${dropzone}/targets/$dir
        fi
        dropzone=${dropzone}/targets/$dir
    else
        usage
    fi
}
```

To pass in all args use $* as parameter -:

```
  validate_args $*
```

And finally call the script like this for getopt to parse correctly-:

```
  myscript.sh -d dir_name
```

Comment: Thanks @suspectus (+1) - when I make all those changes (please see my edit to the original question) I now have 2 lines that are in error: `myscript.sh: 5: myscript.sh: validate_args: not found
myscript.sh: 6: myscript.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`.

Comment: Thanks again, but I have made all of your recommended changes and still getting errors. It looks like I am correctly using `getopt` but for some reason bash isn't liking me.

Comment: bash doesn't like me sometimes either. :)

Comment: Thanks @suspectus (+1 again) - I applied your changes, which thankfully got rid of the `getopt` errors, but now 2 things are happening: (1) it can't create the desired directory, and (2) running the script requires me to type `-dsomeDir` for arguments instead of `-d=someDir`. Please see my updated error section in the original question...and thanks again, **enormously**!!

Comment: Sorry in haste I forgot to mention two salient points. see edits.

Answer (score 1):

When invoked, a function is indistinguishable from a command — so you don't use parentheses:

```
validate_args($1)  # Wrong
validate_args $1   # Right
```

Additionally, as [suspectus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1827600/suspectus) points out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16176053/), functions must be defined before they are invoked. You can see this with the script:

```
usage

usage()
{
    echo "Usage: $0" >&2
    exit 1
}
```

which will report `usage: command not found` assuming you don't have a command or function called `usage` available.  Place the invocation after the function definition and it will work fine.

---

Your chosen interface is not the standard Unix calling convention for commands.  You'd normally use:

```
dropzone -d subdir
```

rather than

```
dropzone -d=subdir
```

However, we can handle your chosen interface (but not using `getopts`, the built-in command interpreter, and maybe not using GNU `getopt` either, and certainly not using `getopt` as you tried to do so).  Here's workable code supporting `-d=subdir`:
    #!/bin/bash

```
dropzone="$HOME/app/dropzone/targets"

validate_args()
{
    case "$1" in
    (-d=*)  dropzone="$dropzone/${1#-d=}"; mkdir -p $dropzone;;
    (*)     usage;;
    esac
}

usage()
{
    echo "Usage: $0 -d=dropzone" >&2
    exit 1
}

# Validate script arguments.
validate_args $1

# Go to the dropzone directory.
cd $dropzone || exit 1
echo "Arrived at dropzone $dropzone."

# The script will now do other stuff, now that we're in the "dropzone".
# ...etc.
```

Note the cautious approach with the `cd $dropzone || exit 1`; if the `cd` fails, you definitely do not want to continue in the wrong directory.

Using the `getopts` built-in command interpreter:

```
#!/bin/bash

dropzone="$HOME/app/dropzone/targets"

usage()
{
    echo "Usage: $0 -d dropzone" >&2
    exit 1
}

while getopts d: opt
do
    case "$opt" in
    (d) dropzone="$dropzone/$OPTARG"; mkdir -p $dropzone;;
    (*) usage;;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

# Go to the dropzone directory.
cd $dropzone || exit 1
echo "Arrived at dropzone $dropzone."

# The script will now do other stuff, now that we're in the "dropzone".
# ...etc.
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Leffler (+1) - please see my comment underneath suspectus' answer - I have the same question for you!

Comment: Note that the function syntax is `funcname() { ...body... }` with parentheses in the definition (and with `bash`, optionally `function funcname() { ...body... }`).  You're not including the parentheses in the definition — as you need to — whereas originally you were including parentheses in the invocation — which you must not do.

Comment: Thanks again (+1) - I edited my question to show what happens when I add the parens to the function defs, and the resulting error messages. Basically, it gets rid of the 1st and last error message but still leaves me with 5 `getopt` errors and 2 other errors relating to `dropzone`.

Comment: Various comments: if the directory already exists, there's not much point in creating it again (it will fail).  Using `mkdir -p "$dropzone/targets/$d"` would work unconditionally.  Your use of `getopt` is unorthodox in the extreme, and the `=` notation might be handled by the GNU version of `getopt` but not by others.  More comments later, if you're lucky...work is pending.