# Parsing bash function parameters

Tags: bash, function, parameter-passing, string-parsing

I have a bash function, say `foo ()`

I pass some parameters in a string like `user=user1 pass=pwd address=addr1 other=`
Parameters may be missed or passed with random sequence
I need to assign appropriate values inside the `foo`

```
USER=...
PASSWORD=...
ADDRESS=...
```

How can I do it?

I can use `grep` multiple times, but this way is not good, eg

```
foo ()
{
  #for USER
  for par in $* ; do 
    USER=`echo $par | grep '^user='` 
    USER=${USER#*=} 
  done
  #for PASSWORD
  for ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
#!/bin/sh
# usage: sh tes.sh username password addr

# Define foo
# [0]foo [1]user [2]passwd [3]addr
foo () {
    user=$1
    passwd=$2
    addr=$3
    echo ${user} ${passwd} ${addr}
}

# Call foo
foo $1 $2 $3
```

Result:

```
$ sh test.sh username password address not a data
username password address
```

Your question is also already answered here:

[Passing parameters to a Bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212219/passing-parameters-to-a-bash-function)

---

Apparently the above answer isn't related to the question,
so how about this?

```
#!/bin/sh

IN="user=user pass=passwd other= another=what?"

arr=$(echo $IN | tr " " "\n")

for x in $arr
do
    IFS==
    set $x
    [ $1 = "another" ] && echo "another = ${2}"
    [ $1 = "pass" ] && echo "password = ${2}"
    [ $1 = "other" ] && echo "other = ${2}"
    [ $1 = "user" ] && echo "username = ${2}"
done
```

Result:

```
$ sh test.sh
username = user
password = passwd
other =
another = what?
```

Comment: Not completelly, the set of parameters is not strictly sequnsed. I can pass `address=addr1 pass=pwd user=user1  other=` or just miss some of parameters. So USER may be $1 or $2 or another

Comment: My bad. but you should add those details to your question

Comment: Thanks, this good! But I did use own solution. FYI `params=\`echo $* | tr " " "\n"\` ; USER=\`echo $params | grep ^user=\`` ; `USER=${USER#*=}` ; `PASSWORD=\`echo $params | grep ^pass=\` ; PASSWORD=${PASSWORD#*=}\``