# How to call a function with parameter in Shell

Tags: linux, shell

I have defined a function that takes a parameter

```
function expandSession()
{
    line=$1;
....
}
```

How can I call this function with a parameter?

I tried:

```
expandSession $line;
```

Giving error as

```
expandSession: command not found
```

---

Full code:

```
if [ ! -z "$HOMESERVER" ] ; then
....
                while [[ "$START_DATE" -le "$END_DATE" ]];
                do
                        zgrep ...; do
                            expandSession $line; <------
                        done
                        grep -e ...; do
                            expandSession $line; <------
                        done
                        let START_DATE+=86400;
                done
fi
expandSession ()
{
    line=$1;

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing parameters to a bash function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212219/passing-parameters-to-a-bash-function)

Comment: Your function definition and call is correct. What the error message says is that there's no `expandSession` command or function defined when you call it. Check the spelling, check if it's been really defined etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@BlueMoon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185155/how-to-call-a-function-with-parameter-in-shell/27185593?noredirect=1#comment42857557_27185155) is on the right track: the function is not in scope. **A common error is to ignore the evaluation sequence, and place a function definition *after* the call to it.**

Comment: hi,do i need to import something here. tried removing function but giving the same error

Comment: thanks for that highlighted part.was defining after call..:-)