# Syntax error when creating bash function with an argument

Tags: bash, function, unix, arguments

```
function y-dl ($URL) {
cd ~/Music/
youtube-dl -f bestaudio --prefer-ffmpeg --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 $URL > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

I'm trying to write a bash function for my bash profile that downloads YouTube Audio without any verbosity in stderr or stdout but I get the following compilation error:

```
-bash: /Users/mu/.bash_profile: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `$URL'
-bash: /Users/mu/.bash_profile: line 11: `function y-dl ($URL) {'
```

I'm trying a variant of the top answer from [Passing parameters to a Bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212219/passing-parameters-to-a-bash-function) but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Functions do not take a parameter list in their definition.  And the keyword 'function' is redundant.  Just write: `y_dl() { ... }`  (And don't use a hyphen in the name)

Comment: Within the function, parameters are referenced by number, but you can name them explicitly. `local URL=$1`

Comment: Re: the `function` keyword, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: ...that linked-to answer doesn't show the `()` string being modified. Why are you modifying it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct and modern way :

```
y-dl() {
    cd ~/Music/
    youtube-dl -f bestaudio --prefer-ffmpeg --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 "$1" &>/dev/null
}
```

function construction never takes arguments in a *signature* style Ex: `func(foo, bar)` it's shell