# Pass second argument into Bash Function

Tags: bash, arguments

How would I pass the 2nd argument into a bash function called `setdb`?
I ask the user to enter a command. If the user enters `setdb test`, I want to pass test into the function `setdb`. Then I want to run a file test on it to see if test.txt exists.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Setdb. Checks if the file exist, read, does not exist, 
setdb () {
    if [[ -e $FILE && -r $FILE ]]; then 
        echo "Database set to" $FILE
    elif [! -f $FILE  && -w $FILE ]; then
        touch datbase.txt
        echo "File database created. Database set to database.txt"
    fi
}

while read answer; do
    if [[ $answer == "setdb" ]]; then 
        setdb
    fi
done
```

Comment: I removed a bunch of irrelevant stuff from your question and improved the indenting for readability. Please read [mre], and [ask] more generally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing parameters to a Bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212219/passing-parameters-to-a-bash-function)

Comment: setdb $2                                                                                                                                        setdb() { if [[ -e $2 && -r $2 ]]; then......                would that be correct?

Comment: for future reference https://shellcheck.net

Comment: @Dynamics : In this case, the $2 passed to `setdb` will be of course $1 inside `setdb`, hence `setdb() { if [[ -e $1 && -r $1 ]]; then`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the `select` statement: then your users won't have to type so much:

```sh
setdb () {...}
func2 () {...}
func3 () {...}

PS3="Which function to run?"

select f in setdb func2 func3 quit; do
    case $f in
        setdb)
            read -p "Database name: " db
            setdb "$db"
            ;;
        func2) ... ;;
        func3) ... ;;
        quit) break ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: I cannot use select since one of the goals of the assignment is to have the user input the full argument.

Comment: OK, well as this is homework, what thoughts do you have to solve it?

Comment: You can examine the effects of quoting a variable versus leaving it unquoted. Also investigate `set -f`

Comment: I read over passing parameters into a bash function but im thinking arguement $2 which is test(setdb test) is not being recognized.

Comment: Set current database to be be <db> .

If the file exists and is readable, make the file the current database, respond with:
Database set to <db>
If the file exists but is not readable, do not update the current database, respond with
File <db> not readable
If the file does not exist, your script will create the empty named file and respond
File <db> created. Database set to <db>
If no filename is supplied, respond with:
Missing Argument
If too many arguments are supplied, respond with:
Extra arguments ignored