# bash: two independent triggers assosiated with two independent arguments

Tags: bash

In order to define two trigers within my bash script, I am trying to define two different algorithms --sort assosiated with the $MY_SORT_METHOD (may be either 1 or 2) as well as --filt assosiated with $MY_FILT_METHOD (may be 1,2,3 or 4):

```
parse_args() { 
  # default sorting method is 1 (based on the number of the ligand) by default
  MY_SORT_METHOD=1
  # dafault filtering method is 1 (the strategy number1)
  MY_FILT_METHOD=1
  while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
    MY_ARG="$1"
    if [ "${MY_ARG:0:6}" = "--sort" ]; then
      #  sort method argument
      MY_ARG_VALUE="${MY_ARG:6:2}"
      # Check the sort method supplied
      if [ "${MY_ARG_VALUE}" != "=1" -a "${MY_ARG_VALUE}" != "=2" ]; then
         echo "Wrong sorting method was chosen : ${MY_ARG_VALUE}"
         return 1;
      fi
      MY_SORT_METHOD="${MY_ARG_VALUE:1:1}"
    fi
    shift # Shift to next parameters if any
    if [ "${MY_ARG:0:6}" = "--filt" ]; then
      #  sort method argument
      MY_ARG_VALUE="${MY_ARG:6:2}"
      # Check the sort method supplied
      if [ "${MY_ARG_VALUE}" != "=1" -a "${MY_ARG_VALUE}" != "=2" -a "${MY_ARG_VALUE}" != "=3" -a "${MY_ARG_VALUE}" != "=4" ]; then
         echo "Wrong filtering method was chosen : ${MY_ARG_VALUE}"
         return 1;
      fi
      MY_FILT_METHOD="${MY_ARG_VALUE:1:1}"
    fi
    shift # Shift to next parameters if any
  done
  return 0;
}
```

From this point the script works correctly while using either --sort or --filt independently

```
 ./rescoring8.sh --sort=2
Provided command line arguments : --sort=2
Debug info: current sorting method is: 2
Debug info: current filtering strategy is : 1
```

or

```
(base)  ./rescoring8.sh --filt=3
Provided command line arguments : --filt=3
Debug info: current sorting method is: 1
Debug info: current filtering strategy is : 3
```

but in the case of defining the both --sort= and --filt= simultaneously, the second algument is always ignored:

```
(base)  ./rescoring8.sh --sort=2 --filt=3
Provided command line arguments : --sort=2 --filt=3
Debug info: current sorting method is: 2
Debug info: current filtering strategy is : 1
```

How I should fix parse_args()  to resolve the issue ?

Comment: You just have to remove the line ` shift # Shift to next parameters if any` between `fi` and the  `if [ "${MY_ARG:0:6}" = "--filt" ]; then`. The `shift` command will shift the parameters list to the left ($n=>$n-1 .. $2 => $1). You could keep it before the `fi` also, as the current parameter is then identified and parsed.

Comment: Why not use `getopt`? `if [ "${MY_ARG:0:6}" = "--sort" ];`  Ugh, use `case`. `MY_FILT_METHOD="${MY_ARG_VALUE:1:1}"` Ugh, just split the string on `=`. Why all these substrings?

Comment: Right, thank you! I've just removed  shift # Shift to next parameters if any between the both IF and it works correctly now. I am going to try with CASE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all these substrings it's very complicated. Instead take a more abstract approach. Use `case` to compare strings with multiple values - you can also use glob there. Split the input on `=` - it's two parts, value and option.

```
parse_args() { 
  my_sort_method=1
  my_filt_method=1
  while (($#)); do
    case "$1" in
    --sort=*)
        IFS== read -r _ val <<<"$1";
        case "$val" in
        1|2) ;;
        *)
              echo "wrong value"
              return 1
        esac
        my_sort_method="$val"
        ;;
    --filt=*)
        IFS== read -r _ val <<<"$1"
        case "$val" in [0-4]) ;; *)
              echo "wrong value"
              return 1
        esac
        my_filt_method="$val"
        ;;
    esac
    shift
  done
}

parse_args --filt=1 --sort=1
declare -p my_sort_method my_filt_method
parse_args --filt=2 --sort=2
declare -p my_sort_method my_filt_method
```

But anyway, if you can and usually you can, I would recommend using `getopt -l sort:,filt:` and an usual getopt code, which would also make it accept `--filt arg` and is easy extendable.

```
parse_args() { 
  args=$(getopt -o '' -l sort:,filt: -- "$@")
  eval "set -- $args"
  my_sort_method=1
  my_filt_method=1
  set -x
  while (($#)); do
     case "$1" in
     --sort) my_sort_method="$2"; shift; ;;
     --filt) my_filt_method="$2"; shift; ;;
     --) shift; break; ;;
     esac
     shift;
  done
}


parse_args --filt=1 --sort=1
declare -p my_sort_method my_filt_method
parse_args --sort=2 --filt=2 
declare -p my_sort_method my_filt_method
```

Comment: right, thank you! In fact the first method does not work, sending me "wrong value" message when I run script with any fiven arguments like --sort=1 --filt=2 etc, the second one works but always set  --sort=1 and --filt=1 even if I try to provide other values for the both args during script execution

Comment: Please DO NOT COPY RANDOM CODE FROM INTERNET AND RUN IT. You did fix the typos? Like there's `read val` followed by `case "$var"`? Do you see `val` vs `var`?

Comment: i only changed the name to my variables since the structure was clean for me and I could not find typos there :-) m.b. the problem is how I run the function inside the bash script, which I do using parse_args $*.  ???

Comment: Here fixed typos and tested on [repl](https://replit.com/@kamilcukrowski/ViciousPoisedRange#main.sh)

Comment: OK!! the second one (which seems to me more compact and easy for understanding ) still does not work, m.b. we are using two different shells (i am on mac OSX with bash terminal)

Comment: also just fixed bug in the first version,  case "$val" in [1-4]) ;; *).     since --filt is from 1 to 4 (zero produced error of the script, since this value does not assosiated with anything..