# I am new to the bash zsh scripting and i need some help aliases and how to pass parameters to them

Tags: alias

thank you in advance for your help
i need to create aliases from this shell commands and i can't figure out how to pass parameters to them

```
    WINEPREFIX=/folder/to/the/bottle/as/a/parameter winetricks
    ( $1 >/dev/null 2>&1 &)
    grep -Rnw '$1' -e '$2'
    aria2c -x10 -V --optimize-concurrent-downloads '$1'`
```

excuse me for my bad english
and thank you in advance AGAIN!!

this not WORKING

```
    alias exe='(( $1 >/dev/null 2>&1 & ))'
    alias wp='WINEPREFIX=$1 wintricks'
    alias aria="aria2c -x10 -V --optimize-concurrent-downloads '$1'"
    alias tfind="grep -Rnw '$1' -e '$2'"
```

Comment: Aliases don't take arguments. Use a function. c.f. [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212219/passing-parameters-to-a-bash-function). Also, throwing away all your output, especially errors, is *very* rarely a good idea...

Comment: Thank you fir help !! that's help me a lot !!