# How to pass array as an argument to a function in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

As we know, in bash programming the way to pass arguments is `$1`, ..., `$N`. However, I found it not easy to pass an array as an argument to a function which receives more than one argument. Here is one example:

```
f(){
 x=($1)
 y=$2

 for i in "${x[@]}"
 do
  echo $i
 done
 ....
}

a=("jfaldsj jflajds" "LAST")
b=NOEFLDJF

f "${a[@]}" $b
f "${a[*]}" $b
```

As described, function `f`receives two arguments: the first is assigned to `x` which is an array, the second to `y`.

`f` can be called in two ways. The first way use the `"${a[@]}"` as the first argument, and the result is:

```
jfaldsj 
jflajds
```

The second way use the `"${a[*]}"` as the first argument, and the result is:

```
jfaldsj 
jflajds 
LAST
```

Neither result is as I wished. So, is there anyone having any idea about how to pass array between functions correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing arrays as parameters in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063347/passing-arrays-as-parameters-in-bash)

Comment: @chepner thanks for reminding. I will check it later for some ideas

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063347/passing-arrays-as-parameters-in-bash

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You cannot pass an array, you can only pass its elements (i.e. the expanded array).

```
#!/bin/bash
function f() {
    a=("$@")
    ((last_idx=${#a[@]} - 1))
    b=${a[last_idx]}
    unset a[last_idx]

    for i in "${a[@]}" ; do
        echo "$i"
    done
    echo "b: $b"
}

x=("one two" "LAST")
b='even more'

f "${x[@]}" "$b"
echo ===============
f "${x[*]}" "$b"
```

The other possibility would be to pass the array by name:

```
#!/bin/bash
function f() {
    name=$1[@]
    b=$2
    a=("${!name}")

    for i in "${a[@]}" ; do
        echo "$i"
    done
    echo "b: $b"
}

x=("one two" "LAST")
b='even more'

f x "$b"
```

Comment: pass the array by name? can you make it more clear. I found you just make it possible

Comment: @RedLv: Just pass the name of the array and use parameter expansion with `!` to get the array.

Comment: note that the value of the "name" variable is merely the string "x[@]". The magic occurs with the `${!...}`

Comment: @choroba great this idea is perfect when the function to be called is in the same file with the caller. unfortunately, I need to pass the array and other value as arguments to a script to be executed in the remote host by the ssh user@host cmd command. Do you have any suggestion about how to make it possible. By the way, do you have any reference about the "by name" mechanism.

Comment: @RedLv: The first solution should work, you just have to escape the cmd properly. Parameter expansion is described in `man bash`.

Comment: Just a note:
 Passing array by name => passing by reference. Any change in the called function will change the global value. Besides, arrays local to function cannot be passed.

Comment: In function `f`, `a` is a copy of the array.

Comment: @choroba If I declare name as `name=$1` instead of `name=$1[@]`m this doesn't. That part really looks like magic. Can you explain what's going on there? Also, how will this extend to passing associative arrays?

Comment: @shahensha: See [here](/questions/4069188/how-to-pass-an-associative-array-as-argument-to-a-function-in-bash) on how to pass an associative array by name. It's even uglier than passing a normal array :-)

Comment: @anishsane Posted today [a robust way using recent nameref and an alternative field separator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75033037/1765658) on a similar SO question.

Comment: Is `name` needed? Can `$1[@]` be used in `("${!name}")` instead of `name`?

Comment: @user2023370 What happened when you tried?

Comment: @choroba If I tried and it fails, there may still be another way to make it work. Perhaps you know already?

Comment: I used the trick with `name` because it's the only way I know it can be done.

Comment: I've just noticed the answer below from @EdouardThiel. I am using a version of bash newer than 4.3 so I am going for that.

Answer (score 84):

You can pass an array by name reference to a function in bash (since version 4.3+), by setting the `-n` attribute:

```
show_value () # array index
{
    local -n myarray=$1
    local idx=$2
    echo "${myarray[$idx]}"
}
```

This works for indexed arrays:

```
$ shadock=(ga bu zo meu)
$ show_value shadock 2
zo
```

It also works for associative arrays:

```
$ declare -A days=([monday]=eggs [tuesday]=bread [sunday]=jam)
$ show_value days sunday
jam
```

See also `nameref` or `declare -n` in the man page.

Comment: Best answer if your shell supports it. Lightest code. Straight-forward. Thank you :>

Comment: The drawback is that you must use in the function another name for the array that in the calls.

Comment: CentOS 7 (centos-release-7-7.1908.0.el7.centos.x86_64) does not support this due to its default bash version is 4.2.26

Comment: In `show_value`, one of `myarray` or `array` is probably a typo.  They should probably be the same name.

Comment: Well seen, fixed. Thanks :)

Comment: This is the best way! It would be even better if referring to [the online manual for declare builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-declare). Unfortunately this neat trick doesn’t work in Zsh, which lacks the `-n` flag for [`declare`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-typeset).

Comment: I don't like pass-by-name because the array cannot be made "local" to the calling function

Answer (score 19):

You could pass the "scalar" value first. That would simplify things:

```
f(){
  b=$1
  shift
  a=("$@")

  for i in "${a[@]}"
  do
    echo $i
  done
  ....
}

a=("jfaldsj jflajds" "LAST")
b=NOEFLDJF

f "$b" "${a[@]}"
```

At this point, you might as well use the array-ish positional params directly

```
f(){
  b=$1
  shift

  for i in "$@"   # or simply "for i; do"
  do
    echo $i
  done
  ....
}

f "$b" "${a[@]}"
```

Comment: You idea can work out in this case. However it doesn't hit the point of passing array as arguments.

Comment: Thanks, this is good. My server's default bash shell's version is below 4.3, your solution is OK.

Comment: I like this because it's easy to understand. Good for versions below 4.3.

Comment: It doesn't and I was wrong, comment deleted, sorry about that!

Comment: No worries, I've done the same myriad times.

Answer (score 4):

This will solve the issue of passing array to function:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo() {
    string=$1
    array=($@)
    echo "array is ${array[@]}"
    echo "array is ${array[1]}"
    return
}
array=( one two three )
foo ${array[@]}
colors=( red green blue )
foo ${colors[@]}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try like this

```
function parseArray {
    array=("$@")

    for data in "${array[@]}"
    do
        echo ${data}
    done
}

array=("value" "value1")

parseArray "${array[@]}"
```

Comment: this should totally be marked as the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Pass the array as a function**

```
array() {
    echo "apple pear"
}

printArray() {
    local argArray="${1}"
    local array=($($argArray)) # where the magic happens. careful of the surrounding brackets.
    for arrElement in "${array[@]}"; do
        echo "${arrElement}"
    done

}

printArray array
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where I receive 2 bash arrays into a function, as well as additional arguments after them. This pattern can be continued indefinitely for *any number of bash arrays* and *any number of additional arguments*, accommodating *any input argument order*, so long as the length of each bash array comes just before the elements of that array.

**Function definition for `print_two_arrays_plus_extra_args`:**

```sh
# Print all elements of a bash array.
# General form:
#       print_one_array array1
# Example usage:
#       print_one_array "${array1[@]}"
print_one_array() {
    for element in "$@"; do
        printf "    %s\n" "$element"
    done
}

# Print all elements of two bash arrays, plus two extra args at the end.
# General form (notice length MUST come before the array in order
# to be able to parse the args!):
#       print_two_arrays_plus_extra_args array1_len array1 array2_len array2 \
#       extra_arg1 extra_arg2
# Example usage:
#       print_two_arrays_plus_extra_args "${#array1[@]}" "${array1[@]}" \
#       "${#array2[@]}" "${array2[@]}" "hello" "world"
print_two_arrays_plus_extra_args() {
    i=1

    # Read array1_len into a variable
    array1_len="${@:$i:1}"
    ((i++))
    # Read array1 into a new array
    array1=("${@:$i:$array1_len}")
    ((i += $array1_len))

    # Read array2_len into a variable
    array2_len="${@:$i:1}"
    ((i++))
    # Read array2 into a new array
    array2=("${@:$i:$array2_len}")
    ((i += $array2_len))

    # You can now read the extra arguments all at once and gather them into a
    # new array like this:
    extra_args_array=("${@:$i}")

    # OR you can read the extra arguments individually into their own variables
    # one-by-one like this
    extra_arg1="${@:$i:1}"
    ((i++))
    extra_arg2="${@:$i:1}"
    ((i++))

    # Print the output
    echo "array1:"
    print_one_array "${array1[@]}"
    echo "array2:"
    print_one_array "${array2[@]}"
    echo "extra_arg1 = $extra_arg1"
    echo "extra_arg2 = $extra_arg2"
    echo "extra_args_array:"
    print_one_array "${extra_args_array[@]}"
}
```

Example usage:

```sh
array1=()
array1+=("one")
array1+=("two")
array1+=("three")

array2=("four" "five" "six" "seven" "eight")

echo "Printing array1 and array2 plus some extra args"
# Note that `"${#array1[@]}"` is the array length (number of elements
# in the array), and `"${array1[@]}"` is the array (all of the elements
# in the array) 
print_two_arrays_plus_extra_args "${#array1[@]}" "${array1[@]}" \
"${#array2[@]}" "${array2[@]}" "hello" "world"
```

Example Output:

```
Printing array1 and array2 plus some extra args
array1:
    one
    two
    three
array2:
    four
    five
    six
    seven
    eight
extra_arg1 = hello
extra_arg2 = world
extra_args_array:
    hello
    world
```

For further examples and detailed explanations of how this works, see my longer answer on this topic here: [Passing arrays as parameters in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70855715/4561887)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a json file with an array, and then parse that json file with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

For example:

my-array.json:

```
{
  "array": ["item1","item2"]
}
```

script.sh:

```
ARRAY=$(jq -r '."array"' $1 | tr -d '[],"')
```

And then call the script like:

```
script.sh ./path-to-json/my-array.json
```