# How to pass an array argument to the Bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, arguments

It is surprising me that I do not find the answer after 1 hour search for this.
I would like to pass an array to my script like this:

```
test.sh argument1 array argument2
```

I DO NOT want to put this in another bash script like following:

```
array=(a b c)
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
  test.sh argument1 $i argument2
done
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1063367/2235132

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Bash arrays are not "first class values" -- you can't pass them around like one "thing".

Assuming `test.sh` is a bash script, I would do

```
#!/bin/bash
arg1=$1; shift
array=( "$@" )
last_idx=$(( ${#array[@]} - 1 ))
arg2=${array[$last_idx]}
unset array[$last_idx]

echo "arg1=$arg1"
echo "arg2=$arg2"
echo "array contains:"
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}"
```

And invoke it like

```
test.sh argument1 "${array[@]}" argument2
```

Comment: Great answer. I know this doesn't conform to OP's requirement of `test.sh argument1 array argument2` but if the invocation was changed to `test.sh argument1 argument2 array` (the array being the last), it'd be less work.

Comment: Good answer. But technically it is not passing array to a script. What if OP needs to pass 2 array variables to this script like `test.sh argument1 array1 array2`

Comment: Note that you need to declare the array before calling the script. For the OP, this would mean `$ array=(a b c)` and then `test.sh argument1 "${array[@]}" argument2` . It might only be me who had to think about that a bit, but I'm commenting in the hope that it will help someone.

Comment: @anubhava Finally, ten year further, I published [another correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75764948/1765658), I think.

Answer (score 19):

Have your script `arrArg.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

arg1="$1"
arg2=("${!2}")
arg3="$3"
arg4=("${!4}")

echo "arg1=$arg1"
echo "arg2 array=${arg2[@]}"
echo "arg2 #elem=${#arg2[@]}"
echo "arg3=$arg3"
echo "arg4 array=${arg4[@]}"
echo "arg4 #elem=${#arg4[@]}"
```

Now setup your arrays like this in a shell:

```
arr=(ab 'x y' 123)
arr2=(a1 'a a' bb cc 'it is one')
```

And pass arguments like this:

```
. ./arrArg.sh "foo" "arr[@]" "bar" "arr2[@]"
```

Above script will print:

```
arg1=foo
arg2 array=ab x y 123
arg2 #elem=3
arg3=bar
arg4 array=a1 a a bb cc it is one
arg4 #elem=5
```

**Note:** It might appear weird that I am executing script using `. ./script` syntax. Note that this is for executing commands of the script in the **current shell environment**.

**Q.** Why current shell environment and why not a sub shell?
**A.** Because bash doesn't export array variables to child processes as [documented here by bash author himself](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg01774.html)

Comment: what if any of the array elements contain whitespace?

Comment: @anubhava, thanks very much. The elements of my array have no space. But both yours and glenn's answers are nice.

Comment: When i run your code, 

arg2=("${!2}")
for this line i am getting Bad Substitution

Comment: This is super, super clever and made my shells scripts awesome!

Comment: @glennjackman Posted today [a robust way using recent nameref and an alternative field separator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75033037/1765658)

Comment: worked for me.  Its very Important to use ". ./script" syntax

Answer (score 12):

**If values have spaces** (and as a general rule) I vote for [glenn jackman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17233006/1121497), but I'd simplify it by passing the array as the last argument. After all, it seems that you can't have multiple array arguments, unless you do some complicated logic to detect their boundaries.

So I'd do:

```
ARRAY=("the first" "the second" "the third")
test.sh argument1 argument2 "${ARRAY[@]}"
```

which is the same as:

```
test.sh argument1 argument2 "the first" "the second" "the third"
```

And in `test.sh` do:

```
ARG1="$1"; shift
ARG2="$1"; shift
ARRAY=("$@")
```

---

**If values have no spaces** (i.e. they are urls, identifiers, numbers, etc) here's a simpler alternative. This way you can actually have multiple array arguments and it's easy to mix them with normal arguments:

```
ARRAY1=(one two three)
ARRAY2=(four five)
test.sh argument1 "${ARRAY1[*]}" argument3 "${ARRAY2[*]}"
```

which is the same as:

```
test.sh argument1 "one two three" argument3 "four five"
```

And in `test.sh` you do:

```
ARG1="$1"
ARRAY1=($2) # Note we don't use quotes now
ARG3="$3"
ARRAY2=($4)
```

I hope this helps. I wrote this to help (you and me) understand how arrays work, and how `*` an `@` work with arrays.

Answer (score 4):

### Passing array as argument to script by using alternate separator

And passing array as argument to **remote** script by using alternate separator

#### Practical sample:

Choosing *bell* character: ascii `0x07` used by C sequence: `\a`.

Little preparation: Having a function to prepare variables:

```bash
mergeArray() {
    local IFS=$'\a'
    local -n src=$1 tgt=$2
    tgt=${src[*]}
}
```

Then the *script* could look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

arg1="$1"
IFS=$'\a' read -ra arg2 <<<"$2"
arg3="$3"

declare -p arg{1,2,3}
```

In practice:

```bash
var1=Hello var2=(foo bar baz) var3=world.
mergeArray var2 mvar2
bash script "$var1" "$mvar2" "$var3"
```

must output:

```
declare -- arg1="Hello"
declare -a arg2=([0]="foo" [1]="bar" [2]="baz")
declare -- arg3="world."
```

### Explanations

- by using `local IFS=` I ensure `IFS` varialbe won't be modified in environment
- `local -n` is a *nameref* for binding variables.
- `${src[*]}` will merge all elements of array to one string by using 1st character of `$IFS`
- Of course, I use `\a` for this, this could replaced (on both side) by any other single byte non null character (ascii) from `\1` to `\377`, while choosed character is not used in your array.

### Installation and remote execution

The function `mergeArray` could be installed into your `.bashrc` file or into a separated file to be sourced before you run your script.

Once done, the *script* himself could even be located **remotely**. then run by same command:

```
ssh user@remote /path/to/script  "$var1" "$mvar2" "$var3"
```

But for more robust remote execution I prefer:

```bash
myArray=("foo bar baz" 'alice bob charlie' 'strawberry raspberry')
mergeArray myArray mergedArray
var1="Hello world!"
ssh user@remote /bin/bash -s <<eoRemote
    /path/to/script  "$var1" "$mergedArray" "This seem nice, isnt't it?"
eoRemote
```

From my remote host, I will read:

```
declare -- arg1="Hello world!"
declare -a arg2=([0]="foo bar baz" [1]="alice bob charlie" [2]="strawberry raspberry")
declare -- arg3="This seem nice, isnt't it?"
```

( Notice the mixing of single quotes and double quotes!! ;-)

### Passing Associative arrays as argument to remote bash via ssh

Things become a little stronger!

```bash
mergeArray () { 
    local -n _srce=${1?Source var missing.} _trgt=${2?Target var missing.}
    local  _tvar
    IFS=\  read _ _tvar _ <<< "${_srce@A}"
    case ${_tvar#-} in 
        *a*)  local IFS=$'\a'; _trgt=${_srce[*]} ;;
        *A*)  _trgt=''
              for _tvar in "${!_srce[@]}" ;do
                  printf -v _tvar '%s\a%s\a' "$_tvar" "${_srce[$_tvar]}"
                  _trgt+="$_tvar"
              done
              _trgt=${_trgt%$'\a'} ;;
        *  ) printf >&2 '%s ERROR: Variable "%s" is not an array.\n' \
                 $FUNCNAME "$1"
             return 1 ;;
    esac
}
```

Then parsing args in script will become:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

arg1=${1}

IFS=$'\a' read -ra arg2 <<<"$2"

IFS=$'\a' read -ra _tmpvar <<<"$3"
printf -v _tmpvar '[%s]="%s" ' "${_tmpvar[@]//\"/\\\"}"
declare -A arg3="($_tmpvar)"

arg4=$4

declare -p arg{1,2,3,4}
```

In action:

```bash
var1="Hello world!"
myArray=("foo bar baz" 'alice bob charlie' 'strawberry raspberry')
declare -A myAArray='([Full name]="John Doo" [Birth date]="1970/01/02 12:34:56"
    [Status]="Maried" [Title]="Chief")'
mergeArray myArray mergedArray
mergeArray myAArray mergedAArray
ssh user@remote /bin/bash -s <<eoRemote
    /path/to/script  "$var1" "$mergedArray" "$mergedAArray" "Still seem nice, isn't it?"
eoRemote
```

```
declare -- arg1="Hello world!"
declare -a arg2=([0]="foo bar baz" [1]="alice bob charlie" [2]="strawberry raspberry")
declare -A arg3=(["Birth date"]="1970/01/02 12:34:56" [Title]="Chief" [Status]="Maried" ["Full name"]="John Doo" )
declare -- arg4="Sill seem nice, isn't it?"
```

### Passing complex variables as arguments over ssh

And for holding double-quotes in addition to already supported single-guotes, spaces and others,
remplace `$varNAme` by `${varName//\"/\\\"}`:

```bash
var1="Hello world!"

myArray=("foo bar baz" 'alice bob charlie' 'strawberry raspberry')

declare -A myAArray='([Full name]="John Doo" [Birth date]="1970/01/02 12:34:56"
    [Status]="Maried")'
myAArray[Title]="Chief's pain sufferer"
myAArray[datas]='{ "height": "5.5 feet", "weight":"142 pounds",'
myAArray[datas]+=$' "phrase": "Let\'s go!" }'

mergeArray myArray mergedArray
mergeArray myAArray mergedAArray

ssh user@remote /bin/bash -s <<eoRemote
    /path/to/script  "${var1//\"/\\\"}" "${mergedArray//\"/\\\"}" \
        "${mergedAArray//\"/\\\"}" "This still seem nice, isn't it?"
eoRemote
```

```
declare -- arg1="Hello world!"
declare -a arg2=([0]="foo bar baz" [1]="alice bob charlie" [2]="strawberry raspberry")
declare -A arg3=([Title]="Chief's pain sufferer" [Status]="Maried" ["Birth date"]="1970/01/02 12:34:56" ["Full name"]="John Doo" [datas]="{ \"height\": \"5.5 feet\", \"weight\":\"142 pounds\", \"phrase\": \"Let's go!\" }" )
declare -- arg4="This still seem nice, isn't it?"
```

Or after some foldering:

```
declare -- arg1="Hello world!"

declare -a arg2=([0]="foo bar baz" [1]="alice bob charlie"
                 [2]="strawberry raspberry" )

declare -A arg3=([Title]="Chief's pain sufferer" [Status]="Maried"
                 ["Birth date"]="1970/01/02 12:34:56" ["Full name"]="John Doo"
                 [datas]="{ \"height\": \"5.5 feet\", \"weight\":\"142 pounds\",
                            \"phrase\": \"Let's go!\" }" )

declare -- arg4="This still seem nice, isn't it?"
```

> ( By adding: `jq <<<${arg3[datas]}` at end of my `script`, I see:
>
> ```json
> {
>   "height": "5.5 feet",
>   "weight": "142 pounds",
>   "phrase": "Let's go!"
> }
> ```
>
> :-)

Comment: This is a very good answer with lot of details

Comment: @anubhava Please have a look at my add about associative arrays: If you know a simplier way avoiding one loop (or the other;).

Comment: Thanks, I am going to take a close look on updated answer.

Comment: @anubhava replaced parsing loop by `printf -v _tmpvar '[%s]="%s"`...!

Answer (score 2):

You can write your array to a file, then source the file in your script.
e.g.:

array.sh

```
array=(a b c)
```

test.sh

```
source $2
...
```

Run the test.sh script:

```
./test.sh argument1 array.sh argument3
```

Answer (score 2):

if the length of your array is not too long, you can convert the array to a string which joining with ','

file1.sh

```
s=${1}
arr=(`echo ${s} | tr ',' ' '`)  # then we can convert str to arr
```

file2.sh

```
a="1,2,3,4"
sh file1.sh ${a}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Run bash script with arrays as argument, using `getopts`

You said:

> It is surprising me that I do not find the answer after 1 hour search for this

Then surprisingly, 10 years after you asked this, no one did give this answer...

Re-reading my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75033037/1765658), the title of this question and other answers, I realized that for making a script waiting for an array, I'v used another way in [Parallelize stream processing using `bash` + `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75548027/1765658)

Using `getopts`, you could use any flag repetitively on command line:

```bash
./sparallel.sh -t dhclient -t dnsmasq -t rsyncd -b '\b' -a '[' "./filter-<RE>.sh"
```

Where the repititive use of `-t` flag will build and populate an array.

#### Sample

```bash
#!/bin/bash
usage() { echo "Usage: $0 [-a arg] [-aarg]...";}
Array=()
while getopts "ha:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        h ) usage; exit ;;
        a ) Array+=("$OPTARG");;
        ... ) : Some other flags if needed;;
        * ) echo Wrong argument.;exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

printf 'There are now two arrays: "$@" (%d) and "$Array" (%d)\n' $# ${#Array[@]}
echo "${*@A}"
echo "${Array[@]@A}"
```

Then:

```bash
./argArrayTest.sh -a 'Foo bar' -a test -a{a..b}{1,2} Furter args: 'Hello world.'
```

```
There are now two arrays: "$@" (3) and "$Array" (6)
set -- 'Furter' 'args:' 'Hello world.'
declare -a Array=([0]="Foo bar" [1]="test" [2]="a1" [3]="a2" [4]="b1" [5]="b2")
```

#### With your test case:

```bash
array=(a b c)
./argArrayTest.sh "${array[@]/#/-a}" argument1 argument2
```

```
There are now two arrays: "$@" (2) and "$Array" (3)
set -- 'argument1' 'argument2'
declare -a Array=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c")
```

### Same script, with *associative arrays*:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
usage() { echo "Usage: $0 [-a arg] [-aarg]...";}
Array=()
declare -A AArray='()'
while getopts "ha:A:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        h ) usage; exit ;;
        a ) Array+=("$OPTARG");;
        A ) fld="${OPTARG%%=*}" val="${OPTARG#$fld}" AArray["$fld"]="${val#=}";;
        ... ) : Some other flags if needed;;
        * ) echo Wrong argument.;exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

printf 'You now have three arrays: "$@"(%d), "$Array"(%d) and "$AArray"(%d)\n' \
       $# ${#Array[@]} ${#AArray[@]}
echo "${*@A}"
declare -p {A,}Array
```

Usage:

```bash
./argArrayTest.sh -a 'Foo bar' -a test -a{a..b}\ {1,2} -A test=Foo\ bar -A flag \
    -AString==Complex$'\n'"line bounded by =" -Aequal== Furter args: 'Hello world.'
```

```
You now have three arrays: "$@"(3), "$Array"(6) and "$AArray"(4)
set -- 'Furter' 'args:' 'Hello world.'
declare -A AArray=([flag]="" [equal]="=" [String]=$'=Complex\nline bounded by =' [test]="Foo bar" )
declare -a Array=([0]="Foo bar" [1]="test" [2]="a 1" [3]="a 2" [4]="b 1" [5]="b 2")
```

**More complete sample**, permitting `+=` syntax to concatenate strings or add to integers, [on my website](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/argArrayDemo.sh.txt).

### Into a function

Answering [DevSolar's comment on some kind of *duplicate*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063347/passing-arrays-as-parameters-in-bash?noredirect=1#comment133654740_1063347), here is same minimal function you could test directly into any terminal:

```bash
argAryTst() { 
    local OPT{ARG,IND,ERR} opt Array=()
    local -A AArray='()'
    while getopts "a:A:" opt; do
        case $opt in
            a) Array+=("$OPTARG") ;;
            A) fld="${OPTARG%%=*}" val="${OPTARG#$fld}" AArray["$fld"]="${val#=}" ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND-1))
    printf 'You now have three arrays: "$@" (%d), "$%s" (%d) and "$%s" (%d)\n' \
        $# Array ${#Array[@]} AArray ${#AArray[@]}
    echo "${*@A}"
    declare -p {A,}Array
}
```

```bash
argAryTst -a foo -A from=Alice -A to=Bob -a bar\ baz Hello world.
```

```
You now have three arrays: "$@" (2), "$Array" (2) and "$AArray" (2)
set -- 'Hello' 'world.'
declare -A AArray=([from]="Alice" [to]="Bob" )
declare -a Array=([0]="foo" [1]="bar baz")
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution that I'm found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1063367/12387614)

```bash
f() {
    declare -a argAry1=("${!1}")
    echo "${argAry1[@]}"
    # ...
}

arr1=(
    "a"
    "b"
)
f arr1[@] arr2[@] arg2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with the array being the last variable passed and only able to pass one array, then the suggested answer is the absolute best answer; however, it implies a rule that must be followed... that being the array must be last and there is an understood placement of each value passed.

For a completely dynamic way to pass variable/value pairs, with the least amount of rules obeyed, this method seems to work well for me. There are two rules:

1. Values passed are --name/value pairs.
2. Array items must be defined via the --ARRAY {count} pair followed by the --name and the list of values.

This means that to define choices array and validBool array, it would look like:

```
script.sh --varName1 value1               \
          --varName2 value2               \
          --ARRAY 5                       \
          --choices  1 2 3 4 5            \
          --varName3 value3               \
          --ARRAY 2                       \
          --validBool true false          \
          --varName4 value4
```

This yields:

```
varName1="value1";
varName2="value2";
choices=("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
varName3="value3";
validBool=("true", "false");
varName4="value4";
```

As you can see, you can easily pass any type of variable/value pair via this code snippet. What's great is you can store this code snippet in a file "GetArgValues.sh" and "source" include it as needed. NOTE: You can't make it a function because you will have lost the arguments that were passed to the script that invokes it.

Here's the code:

```
# sample:
#   script.sh --varName1 value1 --varName2 value2 --ARRAY 5 --choices 1 2 3 4 5 --varName3 value3 --ARRAY 2 --validBool true false --varName4 value4
# author: Edwin Handschuh

_argCount=$#;
while [[ ${_argCount} -gt 0 ]]; do
    if [[ ${_argCount} -ne 0 ]]; then
        if [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; then
            _varName="${1}";
            if [[ "${_varName:0:2}" != "--" ]]; then
                _rs=16;
                _failureMsg="Invalid name/value pair specified. Name must begin with a '--' characters. Name found '${_varName}'. Aborting script with result status=${_rs}";
                echo "$_failureMsg";
                kill -INT $$;
            fi;
            _varName="${_varName:2:${#_varName}-2}";
            shift;
            _varValue="${1}";
            shift;
            declare -g ${_varName}="${_varValue}";
            if [[ "${_varName}" = "ARRAY" ]]; then
                if [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; then
                    _varName="${1}";
                    if [[ "${_varName:0:2}" != "--" ]]; then
                        _rs=16;
                        _failureMsg="Invalid name/value pair specified. Name must begin with a '--' characters. Name found '${_varName}'. Aborting script with result status=${_rs}";
                        echo "$_failureMsg";
                        kill -INT $$;
                    fi;
                    _varName="${_varName:2:${#_varName}-2}";
                    declare -ga ${_varName};
                    _arrayCounter=$ARRAY;
                    while [[ $ARRAY -gt 0 ]]; do
                        shift;
                        # let "_index = _arrayCounter - ARRAY";
                        ((_index = _arrayCounter - ARRAY));
                        declare -ga "${_varName}[${_index}]"="${1}";
                        ((ARRAY--));
                    done;
                    shift;
                fi;
            fi;
        fi;
    fi;
_argCount=$#;
done
# hey, we're done!
```

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "I would like to pass an array to my script" is too imprecise. You want to be more concrete what you intend to do.

There are two main use cases:

a) You want to pass the contents of an existing array as input to a function (or another script), but you don't want the function to modify the array in any way. In C, you'd call this "by value".

b) You want the function to build a new or modify an existing array and return that array as result. Unfortunately, shells can only return exit codes. An elegant way in Bash 4.2 (4.3) and newer is to pass the name of the array as argument and then declare a local name as a reference. In C, you'd call this "by reference".

The suggested solution to use case a) in this thread is to pass all the array elements as the last arguments of the function call. I don't like that approach, it is considered complex and error-prone. There are at least two other alternatives:

1. Convert the array to a string, pass the string, and rebuild a local copy of the array in the function. You could write your own serialization and deserialization functions. PHP uses explode() and implode() for that purpose and it is not too hard to write bash pendants.
2. Pass the array per reference and just make sure that you treat it as read-only in the function. This is what I've done when I wrote my own implode() function.

The suggested solution to use case b) is documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461656/how-to-pass-array-as-an-argument-to-a-function-in-bash#answer-26443029). Just don't get confused by the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-declare) which states that "*the nameref attribute cannot be applied to array variables*" or [prominent Bash pages](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashWeaknesses#line-30) which claim that "*you can't pass the name of an array to a function and let the function use it*"--it is actually perfectly fine to pass array names as function arguments, the manual warning really refers to *arrays of* name references (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71059826/why-do-the-man-bash-pages-state-the-declare-and-local-n-attribute-cann#answer-71059907)).

When using array variables per reference, you'll sooner or later run into an [issue with circular name references](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302578/circular-name-references-in-bash-shell-function-but-not-in-ksh) which do not exist but are really just implementation flaws (to avoid the term unfixed bugs, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302578/circular-name-references-in-bash-shell-function-but-not-in-ksh#answer-303051)).

Answer (score -4):

If this is your command:

```
test.sh argument1 ${array[*]} argument2
```

You can read the array into test.sh like this:

```
arg1=$1
arg2=${2[*]}
arg3=$3
```

It will complain at you ("bad substitution"), but will work.