# Why doesn't a command with quoted whitespace work when passed over ssh?

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, escaping, quotes

I am building this project in which I have to execute UNIX commands using ssh. Here is my question : When I execute the following command in a UNIX shell,

```
echo "Hello           World"
```

It produces the output :

```
Hello           World
```

With 5 spaces in between as the arguments were given within double quotes. I want to achieve the same effects with ssh as well. I am trying to escape the double quotes using backslash as follows :

```
ssh localhost echo \"Hello           World\"
```

as I do not want bash to process the quotes. But it just produces

```
Hello           World
```

There is only one space after "Hello"
Why is that?

Answer (score 5):

`ssh` executes a command it's given by invoking a remote shell with a script composed of the full set of local arguments concatenated together with whitespace between them.

---

If you run:

```
# This has only syntactic quotes -- none of the quotes are literal.
ssh somehost echo "Hello   World"
```

..then this list of arguments passed to `ssh` (in C syntax, excluding the hostname and the ssh command itself) is `{ "echo", "Hello   World", NULL }`.

Concatenated together into a string, this then becomes `"echo Hello   World"`.

Thus, the remote shell runs `echo Hello   World`, which has no syntactic quotes.

---

If you run:

```
ssh somehost echo \"Hello   World\"
```

...then the list of commands (again, in C syntax) is `{ "echo", "\"Hello", "World\"", NULL }`: The quotes are literal, but the spaces were removed by the local shell (before SSH was run) during the word-splitting process.

Concatenated into a string, this becomes `echo "Hello World"`. Thus, you get quotes, but lose your spaces.

---

By contrast, as a working (but not particularly best-practice) example, consider:

```
ssh somehost echo \"Hello"   "World\"
```

Here, you're passing `ssh` two arguments: The `\"`s at the beginning and end are literal to the first shell (having no syntactical meaning, so the word `Hello` is to that first shell unquoted); but the `"`s just surrounding the whitespace is syntactical, and tells the shell to preserve that whitespace (so the *spaces* are quoted) when invoking `ssh`. Thus, you get `{ "echo", "\"Hello   World\"", NULL }`, which concatenates to the string `echo "Hello   World"`.

---

The best practice is to avoid this behavior by passing only a single string to ssh containing the entire script you want to run.

```
# This works
ssh somehost 'echo "Hello   World"'
```

...if you want to generate that string programatically, you can do so as such (if you know that your remote shell is bash -- even bash-in-`/bin/sh` mode is safe):

```
remote_command=( echo "Hello   World" )
printf -v remote_command_q '%q ' "${remote_command[@]}"
ssh somehost "$remote_command_q"
```

To do that safely with any POSIX-compliant remote shell, see the Python-assisted answer in [How to have simple and double quotes in a scripted ssh command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45308395/how-to-have-simple-and-double-quotes-in-a-scripted-ssh-command)

Comment: What happens when I escape double quotes in the following manner ? ssh somehost echo \"Hello   World\"   Then I don't just have 2 arguments. I have 3. The 3 will be concatenated as "echo \"Hello  World\"". If ssh runs that command, shouldn't it print "Hello  world"?

Comment: ...edited to amend my comments into the answer, so I'm clearing them out of the history here.

Comment: @SudhaSompura, ...did I miss a question there? Passing `echo "Hello World"` to the remote shell (after using escaping to preserve the quotes on the local side), the quotes are (on the remote end) treated as syntactical; they're used to guide string-splitting by the remote shell before the argument vector is passed to `echo`, so the string `echo` gets is `Hello World` (as opposed to two separate arguments, `Hello` and `World`, as would be the case if there had been no syntactic quotes).

Comment: Regarding the "programmatic" approach, can the array idea be applied to a more complex example, such as one with multiple statements?

Comment: @TomFenech, the easiest way to pass multiple statements over ssh reliably is to encapsulate them in a function. `myfunc() { echo "Hello   World"; echo " * Goodbye World * "; }`, and then you can `ssh somehost "$(declare -f myfunc); myfunc"`, and all the quoting/escaping/etc in your function will be represented correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The quotes are present only on the client, and mean that the server sees this:

```
echo Hello     World
```

But the quotes are already lost at this point, so that whitespace is collapsed.

You can use single quotes around the whole command:

```
ssh localhost 'echo "Hello     World"'
```

Now the local shell does not process the string, so the inner quotes remain intact.

---

The case with the escaped quotes means that the quotes are ineffective on the local shell, so the whitespace is collapsed locally, then the server sees:

```
echo "Hello World"
```

Comment: But I have escaped the double quotes, right? It cannot remove the double quotes.

Comment: It doesn't remove the quotes, but the spaces are already lost. I edited to explain.

Comment: @SudhaSompura, keep in mind that there are two shells, not one: There's the local shell, then there's the one running on the other end. Thus, you need to have *two* layers of quoting.