# Why Gitlab CI run commands locally and not on remote machine?

Tags: bash, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

I can't understand. I successfully login on my remote host with ssh during job and i want to be sure that I can run commands at this host. So I have job like this:

```yaml
Deliver image to host:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    # Setup SSH deploy keys
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$PRIVATE_SSH" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

  script:
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <user>@<ip>
    - ls
```

And ls give me output of gitlab runner machine: i see my repository, not items of remote machine.
Why? How should I run commands on remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <user>@<ip>
    - ls
```

The first command runs `ssh` on the gitlab runner. `ssh` isn't interactive at this point (no keyboard is connected to the `ssh` session here). So `ssh` exits. Then you run `ls` on the gitlab runner, which gives you the strange output you are surprised by.

You want to tell the `ssh` command all of what you want it to do, by providing that extra thing as an argument. So try:

```
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <user>@<ip> ls
```

See other answers like [How to execute a remote command over ssh with arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502945/how-to-execute-a-remote-command-over-ssh-with-arguments) and [How do I pass arbitrary arguments to a command executed over SSH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51547753/how-do-i-pass-arbitrary-arguments-to-a-command-executed-over-ssh) for more information on how to exactly provide the commands and arguments to the ssh invocation.

Comment: thank you. Is this the only way: <ssh login> <command> or there is a way to open kind of session?

Comment: See the linked answers for some other techniques, but I find it sanity-preserving to stick to `ssh command` pattern. `command` can be a script, so you can put everything complex in a bash script, and then execute it via one `ssh` command.