# Bash. Pre-set variables

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

Recently I learned there in bash is possible to pre-set variable. For example:

```
q=2 ./ecq
```

And I get `2` to output with

```
#!/bin/bash
# This file is ./ecq
echo "$q"
```

But with array I got error:

```
mn=( 1 2 3 ) ./pre
```

With `./pre`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "${mn[0]}"
```

I get `(1 2 3)`.
**How can I take `mn` pre-set array?**

Comment: Like this `mn=( 1 2 3 ); ./pre`

Comment: @Ivan : In this way, `mn` would not be visible in `pre`.

Comment: @user1934428, right didn't understand the question.

Comment: This post https://stackoverflow.com/a/17233006/2487772 describes what I think is the solution. He passes the array as a string (since arrays are not "first class values") and converts the string into an array in the script itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of a *pre-set variable*, whatever this would be.

The basic syntax of invoking an external command as a child process looks something like

```
a=x b=y c=z p u v w
```

I ignored here redirection operators, to keep things simple. This line basically starts a child process with the command `p` and passes to it the argumenst `u`, `v` and `w`. Every new process needs an **environment**, which is basically a mapping from names (the so-called environment variables) to some strings. The environment for the process `p` is a copy of the environment from the calling process (i.e. your shell script), but enhanced by setting the environment variable `a` to `x`, the variable `b` to `y` and `c` to `z`.

Now you want to set an environment variable having an array as value. This does not work. The value of an environment variable must be a string, because invoking child processes is a general concept (not bound to a certain programming language like bash), and every programming language has some way to deal with a **string** and is supposed to offer a library function to access the environment (For instance the function `getenv` when you are doing C programming). We don't even know whether the programming language used to implement your process `p` does have arrays. Imagine that p is written as POSIX shell scripts - you don't have arrays like you do in bash or zsh, when you are doing POSIX shell.