# Why do the `man bash` pages state the `declare` and `local` `-n` attribute "cannot be applied to array variables", and yet it can?

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array, associative

Why does `local -n` work on array variables when the manual *explicitly says it does not*? Is the manual wrong? Is this relying on some sort of bash "undefined behavior?" Is the manual out-of-date? Am I missing something?

Here is the information I'm looking at from the bash manual:

Run `man bash` and search for `local [` using the regular expression search pattern `local \[`. It says (emphasis added):

> `local [option] [name[=value] ... | - ]`
>
> For each argument, a local variable named name is created, and assigned  value.  **The
> option  can  be  any of the options accepted by `declare`.**

(See also `help local`).

So, the options that can be passed to the bash `local` built-in command are the same as those of `declare`. Let's find what options can be passed to `declare`:

Run `man bash` and search for `declare [` using the regular expression search pattern `declare \[`. Under the `-n` entry there for `declare [-aAfFgilnrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]` you'll see (emphasis added):

> `-n`     Give each name the nameref attribute, making it a name  reference  to  another
> variable.   That  other  variable is defined by the value of name.  All references, assignments, and attribute modifications to name, except those using or
> changing  the `-n` attribute itself, are performed on the variable referenced by
> name's value.  **The nameref attribute cannot be applied to array variables.**

(See also `help declare`).

So, despite it saying **"The nameref attribute cannot be applied to array variables,"**, it ***does* work just fine on array variables!**

To prove that, here is a demo of it working fine for **regular bash arrays**:

```sh
function foo {
    # declare a local **reference variable** (hence `-n`) named `data_ref`
    # which is a reference to the value stored in the first parameter
    # passed in
    local -n data_ref="$1"
    echo "${data_ref[0]}"
    echo "${data_ref[1]}"
}

# declare a regular bash "indexed" array
declare -a data
data+=("Fred Flintstone")
data+=("Barney Rubble")
foo "data"
```

Sample output:

> ```
> Fred Flintstone
> Barney Rubble
> ```

...and here is it working just fine on **associative bash arrays** (ie: bash hash tables, "dictionaries", or "unordered maps"):

```sh
function foo {
    # declare a local **reference variable** (hence `-n`) named `data_ref`
    # which is a reference to the value stored in the first parameter
    # passed in
    local -n data_ref="$1"
    echo "${data_ref["a"]}"
    echo "${data_ref["b"]}"
}

# declare a bash associative array
declare -A data
data["a"]="Fred Flintstone"
data["b"]="Barney Rubble"
foo "data"
```

Sample output:

> ```
> Fred Flintstone
> Barney Rubble
> ```

My `bash --version` is `4.4.20(1)-release`, on Linux Ubuntu 18.04:

> ```
> GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
> Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
>
> This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
> There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
> ```

### References:

1. I modified the above code samples from @Todd Lehman's answer here: [How to pass an associative array as argument to a function in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55170447/4561887)

*Note: in case anyone is searching for it, this question itself also answers the questions: "How do I pass a bash array as a parameter to a function?" and "How do I pass a bash associative array as a parameter to a function?"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are applying `-n` to a scalar variable, and then have that nameref point to an array. This is fine.

What you *can't* do is apply `-n` to an array variable to create an array of namerefs:

```
# Declare two variables
declare foo=42 bar=1337

# Make an array of namerefs
declare -n array=(foo bar)    # ERROR

# ${array[0]} is foo so this should print $foo, i.e. 42?
echo "${array[0]}"
```

If you try, Bash stops you:

```
bash: declare: array: reference variable cannot be an array
```

Comment: Ah, this makes sense! That manual certainly is confusing!