# Using array to dynamically pass files to a command in UNIX

Tags: arrays, bash, unix

I have four files (`file_one` to `file_four`), the contents of these files isn't really important. I want to pass three of these files to a command (i.e. `paste` or `awk`) in a particular order as defined by an array.
My array is `order=(two one four)`.
I was hoping to use the array to pass the desired files to the command as input similarly as how you could use `*` (i.e. `paste file_* > combined_file`);

`paste file_${order[@]} > combined_file`

`paste file_"${order[@]}" > combined_file`

`paste file_"${order[*]}" > combined_file`

`paste file_"{${order[@]}}" > combined_file`

`paste file_{"${order[@]}"} > combined_file`

I have looked at different pages ([1](https://delightlylinux.wordpress.com/2017/04/08/put-filenames-in-bash-array/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981439/reading-filenames-into-an-array), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461656/how-to-pass-array-as-an-argument-to-a-function-in-bash) or [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063347/passing-arrays-as-parameters-in-bash))  but I can't get it to to work. A `loop` through the files doesn't work in the case of `paste` or `awk`. I want to pass the files all at once to a command. Seeing as my `UNIX` knowledge is limited I may have misinterpreted some solutions/answers. From what I understand from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29379084/4524755) there might be some issues with how arrays were originally developed in `bash`.

**Desired result:**
`paste file_two file_one file_four > combined_file`

Comment: Doing `paste file_* > combined_file` should work. What error are you getting

Comment: I know it does, but if you read my problem statement its not what I want. I want a particular order and not all the files. I will remove that to avoid confusion. Please see my desired result :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `printf`:

```
paste $(printf "file_%s " ${order[@]}) > combined_file
```

This avoids having to loop through all elements of the `order` array.

---

Alternatively, using bash*ism*, you could use this:

```
paste ${order[@]/#/file_} > combined_file
```

Note the `#` that matches the start of the pattern as mentioned in the bash man page:

> ${parameter/pattern/string}
>
> (...)  If pattern begins with  #,  it  must
>                 match  at the beginning of the expanded value of parameter.

Comment: Awesome, it works! Although with your second solution - if the array is empty or non-existent it just seems to hang. I used wrong array and it seemed to be taking forever before I had to `CRTL+C` the operation. I like the solution without looping through the array. So for that reason I have chosen this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the for loop within $():

```
paste $(for i in ${order[@]}; do echo file_$i; done) > output_file
```

Comment: i think you mean `file_$i` instead of `paste_$i`. But in any case thanks this works as i would like it to.

Comment: Yes, you are right - really must stop trying to answer these questions on my phone!!