# passing array as parameter in bash 3

Tags: arrays, bash

I've refer [Passing arrays as parameters in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063347/passing-arrays-as-parameters-in-bash), but it failed. Here is my test script(both bash 3.0)

The bash version

```
GNU bash, version 3.00.16(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.10)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

The script t.sh

```
fn() {
 local i
 local v1="$1"
 local v2="$2"
 local v3="$3"
 echo "v1=$1"
 echo "v2=$2"
 echo "v3=$3"
 declare -a a1=("${!1}")
 declare -a a2=("${!2}")
 echo "a1:"
 for i in ${!a1[*]} ; do
  echo "  ${a1[$i]}"
 done

 echo "a2:"
 for i in ${!a2[*]} ; do
  echo "  ${a2[$i]}"
 done
}
caller() {
  local a=("a1 a2" "a3" "a4")
  local b=("b1" "b2" "b3" "b4")
  echo "method 1:"
  fn "${a[@]}" "${b[@]}" $1 $2 $3
  echo "method 2:"  # workable on bash 4.2.45
  fn a[@] b[@] $1 $2 $3
}
caller c
```

Output

```
method 1:
v1=(a1 a2 a3 a4)
v2=(b1 b2 b3 b4)
v3=c
a1:
a2:
method 2:
v1=a[@]
v2=b[@]
v3=c
t.sh: array assign: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
t.sh: array assign: line 10: `(a1 a2 a3 a4)'
```

expected output

```
...
a1:
   a1 a2
   a3
   a4
a2:
   b1
   b2
   b3
   b4
```

Comment: I don't get the output you show. I see `v1=a1 a2
v2=a3
v3=a4`.

Comment: are you sure your bash is version 3.0

Comment: bash version 4.1.11(2)

Comment: @DanielYCLin: Perhaps updating your version of bash? I mean, bash v3 is *ancient*... (8 years since the last release, to be exact, and four since v4 was released.) We don't fix K&R C problems anymore, either. ;-) That being said, as you see from my original question, array passing is *still* dodgy, so I am not surprised old versions of bash balk at it.

Comment: I'm not admin, I haven't permission to upgrade system. So, I just want a work around method.

Comment: @DanielYCLin: The linked question has some variations that are not quite as powerful as the accepted answer, but should work on older bash versions as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing arrays as parameters in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063347/passing-arrays-as-parameters-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are having the issue, but I've confirmed operation on `Bash 3.2.25`:

```
./caller.sh
method 1:
v1=a1 a2
v2=a3
v3=a4
a1:

a2:

method 2:
v1=a[@]
v2=b[@]
v3=c
a1:
  a1 a2
  a3
  a4
a2:
  b1
  b2
  b3
  b4
03:36 lakehouse~/scr/tmp> bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (i586-suse-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: I'm forced to use SunOS with sparc CPU and very old bash then you. Maybe that's why your result is different to me.