# Let a function modify a global variable

Tags: arrays, bash, function, global-variables

I've got a function in bash that takes an array as argument

in my case the array is made of "false" values

I define this array in a main script and then i call the function

```
my_function my_array[@]
```

where my_function is defined this way

```
function my_function(){
arg_array=("${!1}")

arg_array[2]="true"
}
```

but if i print the array in the main script i see that the array hasn't been 
modified. Actually the function modifies the "copy" of the argument array and
not the array itself. How can I let the function to modify the source array (
in other programming languages is related to "global" variables..)?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1063347/1030675

Comment: You can have the function modify the global by using the global and not playing the indirection games to "pass" the array as an argument. Alternatively see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Assigning_indirect.2Freference_variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing, in effect, the names of each element of the array. Just pass the name of the array itself. Then use `declare` to set the value of any particular element using indirect parameter expansion.

```
function my_function(){
    elt2="$1[2]"
    declare "$elt2=true"       
}

my_function my_array
```

In `bash` 4.3, named references make this much simpler.

```
function my_function () {
    declare -n arr=$1
    arr[2]=true
}

my_function my_array
```

This only makes sense, though, if you intend to use `my_function` with different global arrays. If `my_function` is only intended to work with the global `my_array`, then you aren't gaining anything by this: just work with the global as-is.

```
function my_function () {
    my_array[2]=true
}
```