# pass an array as argument to mget command

Tags: bash, lftp

I have stored all the filenames which i want to download from the SFTP server in a file. This file is stored in my local machine.

I am trying to pass the contents of the file to an array.

Is it possible to pass this array as an argument to mget?

something like `mget $my_array` where `my_array` has the list of filenames.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing arrays as parameters in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063347/passing-arrays-as-parameters-in-bash)

Comment: something like `mget "${my_array[@]}"` ?

Comment: @Inian: not exactly a duplicate or is it?

Comment: @sjsam: I felt it boiled down to passing the contents of the `my_array` to the command `mget`.

Comment: @Inian `mget "${my_array[@]}"` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all mind that `mget` is an `lftp command`, so it need to be used with the `-c` switch of `lftp`.

Now, considering that the array contains full-paths to files you could do

```
lftp -c mget "${array[@]}"
```

as anonymous user to get these files.

**Example**

```
array=( "ftp://ftp.redhat.com/redhat/brms/5.3.1/SHA256SUM" "ftp://ftp.redhat.com/redhat/brms/5.3.1/brms-p-5.3.1.GA-src.zip" )
lftp -c mget "${array[@]}"
```

would fetch you two files in question.

---

**Why double quote** `${array[@]}`?

When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word, so you can tackle word splitting for file names with spaces in them (though rare).

---

**Edit (Remeber this is not in an `lftp` session but a `bash` session at localhost)**

Suppose you only have the filenames in the bash array like below

```
array=( "SHA256SUM" "brms-p-5.3.1.GA-src.zip" )
```

First do :

```
array=( "${array[@]/#/ftp://ftp.redhat.com/redhat/brms/5.3.1/}" )
# We have just added the ftp server name + path before every file name in array
lftp -c mget "${array[@]}" # Download the files just like that
```

Comment: I don't have the absolute path in the array.
I have the filenames only.

Comment: @DebajyotiMajumdar : Do you have the address of the server + folder where the files are located?

Comment: @DebajyotiMajumdar : I'm not sure if you're already in an lftp session? Please update the question with this detail.

Comment: i am in an lftp session.

Comment: @DebajyotiMajumdar : If you have the server name and working directory, then you might do the trick I'm about to mention in my edit. Also, mget supports only globbing to my knowledge - for example `mget file*` and once within lftp you can't use variables .