# Is it possible to perform array assignment before a command in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash

I am experimenting with passing arrays to a shell script, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063347/passing-arrays-as-parameters-in-bash/6828383#6828383). I wrote a little script that is simply designed to take in the name of an array and print out the array:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1"
echo "${!1}"
arrayVar=("${!1}")
echo "${arrayVar[1]}"
```

I declare an array variable in line with running my script, like so:

```
array=(foo bar test) ./test.sh array[@]
```

Output:

```
|array[@]         # the bars are only here to force the final blank line
|(foo bar test)
|
```

It seems that `array`, instead of actually being an array, is simply the string `(foo bar test)`

Even if I modify my script to echo `array` directly by name instead of indirectly through the positional parameter, I get the same result.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1"
arrayVar=("${!1}")
echo $arrayVar
echo "${arrayVar[1]}"

echo $array
echo "${array[1]}"
```

Output:

```
|array[@]         # the bars are only here to force the final blank line
|(foo bar test)
|
|(foo bar test)
|
```

Am I simply doing something wrong, or does bash not support array assignments before a command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, bash does not support exporting arrays.  This is documented in `man bash`:

> Array variables may not (yet) be exported.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be no support for it.

If `array=(foo bar test) ./test.sh` doesn't do it (`array` gets exported as the literal string `'(foo bar test)'`, then

```
array=(foo bar test); export array; ./test.sh
```

should, and indeed, after exporting, bash reports the array as an exported array (`x` means exported):

```
$ declare -p array
declare -ax array='([0]="foo" [1]="bar" [2]="test")'
```

but this turns out to be a lie:

```
$ env | grep array; echo status=$?
  status=1
```