# How can I chose the array from all the arguments?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, scripting

given array `arr` and string `str` . If I send them to function in the next way:

`func "${arr[@]}" ${str}`

How can I define the array and the string in `func` function?

```
function func {
local arr=....
local str=....
}
```

according to what I understood (**It's correct?**) if I will do: `local arr=("$@")` I will get that:
`arr[0]=the first argument - in this case it's will be all the array`
`arr[1]=str`

(according to my checks `local arr=("$@")` gives array exactly like arr (what that I sent) , **apart of** it's adds `str` as a last element in this array..)

[I don't ask for "how to send array in bash", but, how can I choose the array from all the arguments]

Comment: Do you have to use that order? Using `func "$str" "${arr[@]}"` would make things easier.

Comment: @Socowi I know, in this way you can skip about the first element. But I want to know how can I deal with the case I brought?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing arrays as parameters in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063347/passing-arrays-as-parameters-in-bash)

Comment: There are no array values in `bash`. You are passing all the *elements* of the array as separate arguments, not the array itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$@` are *all* the parameters passed to the function.
Retrieving the last parameter is easy. Just use the last array entry.
Afterwards you have to delete the last entry from the array.

```
function func {
    local arr=("$@")
    local str="${arr[-1]}"
    unset 'arr[-1]'
}
```

Make sure to always call `func` with at least one parameter or the script will fail.

Comment: Why "-1" ? it's not need to be `"${arr[$((${#arr[@]} - 1))]}"`?

Comment: Newer versions of bash allow negative indices. -1 is the last array entry, -2 the second last array entry, and so on.