# How to iterate through a set of variables, then expand the variables in Bash

Tags: bash, variables, iteration

I'm trying to set up a "check if machines are online" script with Bash, but running into an issue of when and where to define the variables so they're expanded properly. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm01="c01 c02 c03"
rm02="d01 d02 d03"
rm10="e11 e22 e33"
for room in rm01 rm02 rm03; do
    echo $room
    for computer in $room; do
        #run various nslookup/ping tests and report
    done
done
exit 0
```

I'm running into issues because I can't find a way to expand `$room` for its corresponding set of computers (in `$rm01`, `$rm02`, `$rm10`) listed at the beginning.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix is to use [variable indirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
for computer in ${!room}; do
```

Relying on [word splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) is rarely the best idea, though. You could use [arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) and [namerefs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) instead (requires Bash 4.3 or newer):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Declare arrays
rm01=(c01 c02 c03)
rm02=(d01 d02 d03)
rm03=(e11 e22 e33)

# Declare room as nameref
declare -n room

# Using nameref as control variable sets room as reference to each variable in turn
for room in rm{01..03}; do
    # Properly quoted array expansion
    for computer in "${room[@]}"; do
        echo "$computer"   # or whatever needs to be done
    done
done
exit 0
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the arrays/nameref method with older bash? I'm stuck on 3.4 because Apple updates its BSD binaries infrequently. The first example is working just fine, thanks.

Comment: @phonedog365 You could install a more recent Bash with Homebrew; I think you're actually on Bash 3.2 with macOS. If you can't use namerefs, you can use indirection as in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063347/passing-arrays-as-parameters-in-bash). Another good read is [BashFAQ/006](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).